# How do I remove an argument from a String without removing any potential duplicates?

Tags: java, arguments, minecraft, args

I am currently working on a Java program that takes the arguments of a person's input (I figured that part out) and then adds it to a string to then send it to another person. However, I'm stuck with this one part, where the first argument is not to be included in the message. I originally thought of `if (!arg.equals(args[0])){}`, but in the case where the first argument is mentioned again in the message, it also removes that from the message. How do I make it remove the first argument without getting rid of any others exactly like it?

My code right now:

```
if (args.length<=0){
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "No player specified.");
        } else {
            if (args.length==1){
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "No message specified");
            } else {
                String message = "";
                for (String arg : args){
                    if (!arg.equals(args[0])){

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the `for-loop` from index one. That way the first argument will not be included at all.

```java
if (args.length <= 0) {
    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "No player specified.");
} else {
    if (args.length == 1) {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "No message specified");
    } else {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            message.append(args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but just for the future, why did you change the 'message' variable into a StringBuilder instead of keeping it as a String?

Comment: Every `String` concatenation copies the whole `String`. When the `String` concatenation is in loop I generally replace it with `StringBuilder` because loops can get out of hand easily and `StringBuilder` stores strings as `byte[]` internally. I remember reading that compiler does replacing for you but I'm not sure if that works every time. So I do it as a habit.

Comment: `String.join("", Arrays.asList(args).subList(1, args.length))` is another way to do this concatenation without (explicitly) using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Taha "I remember reading that compiler does replacing for you" it does if you do something like `args[1] + args[2] + args[3]`; but it doesn't do it if you are concatenating in a loop.